# RPC_HEADER error while phoenix from Zeppelin trying to connect

Tags: apache-zeppelin, apache-phoenix

Installed zeppelin 0.8.0 and added phoenix interpreter ,
when I start querying for the data I am getting this below error , if I try from zeppelin 0.7.3 (adding phoenix interpreter) everything works fine

I am facing this error only when I tried from zeppelin 0.8.0

Query:

```
%pheonix
select * from "tablestest"
```

Error:

org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed after 
attempts=35, exceptions:
Wed Oct 18 14:22:59 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1508336579165, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RPC_HEADER
Wed Oct 18 14:22:59 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1508336579165, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: master/10.20.3.207:16000
Wed Oct 18 14:22:59 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1508336579165, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: master/10.20.3.207:16000
Wed Oct 18 14:23:00 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1508336579165, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: master/10.20.3.207:16000
Wed Oct 18 14:23:01 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1508336579165, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RPC_HEADER
Wed Oct 18 14:23:03 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1508336579165, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RPC_HEADER
Wed Oct 18 14:23:07 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1508336579165, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RPC_HEADER